# Best and most efficient way to differentiate and assign types to timestamp tokens

Tags: parsing, datetime-format, tokenize, value-type, timestamp-with-timezone

I am working on timestamps parsing. The tokenization of the timestamps is being handled with python using the spacy library. Then I am sending over the tokens from python to Java. What I am trying to do now is to assign each token a 'time type' relating to what is it. A potential date assigned a type 'date', a year as 'year' etc. What I am trying to figure is an efficient way to check each token for what it could be. The challenge is to differentiate a date from a month in short format and a year as well. The basic way I can think of is using multiple checks, but I would need to make deductions to differentiate between dates and months (and year if it is in short format) depending on what the first token is assumed to be. Once I have all the token types and their position index, I can then use them to generate a pattern string using DateTimeFormatter class, so that the timestamp can be parsed and saved to DB. Is there another way to achieve this? I also need to be able to handle timestamps with any possible format like for eg. '20111203'. Appreciate for help!

Comment: You can’t handle all possible formats. Someone will invent a new one tomorrow. And `10/11/2021` can be October 11 or 10 November, we can’t tell.

Comment: Neither knowing Python nor spaCy, maybe you will want to specify precisely how the tokens from that library can look?